# R ggplot2 - convert row records to vertical values and use in geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some items that have different eligibility criteria - specifically in this example two variables each with a min and max the values are allowed to take.  I would like to see the coverage of the products by plotting rectangles for each product on a chart that shows the area between the mins and maxs.

**How would you go about**

- converting the records most elegantly to that required by geom_polygon() and
- ensuring the shapes produced appear as rectangles

**Example**

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.table(Product=letters[1:10], minX=1:10, maxX=5:14, minY= 10:1, maxY=14:5)

df.t<-data.table(rbind( df[,list(Product,X=minX,Y=minY)],
       df[,list(Product,X=minX,Y=maxY)],
       df[,list(Product,X=maxX,Y=minY)],
       df[,list(Product,X=maxX,Y=maxY)]))[
      order(Product,X,Y)]

ggplot(df.t,aes(x=X,y=Y,group=Product,fill=Product))+geom_polygon()
```

[image: Result]

NB In this reduced example there are only two criteria, however I have a range of criteria columns and would not want to repeat the exercise above for different combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your original data frame `df` and then `geom_rect()` as you already have minimal and maximal values for the `x` and `y`.

```
ggplot(df,aes(xmin=minX,xmax=maxX,ymin=minY,ymax=maxY,fill=Product))+geom_rect()
```

[image]

Comment: D'oh, deceptively simple, shoulda RTFMd more